# Source code lost. Minified file available. How to unminify the file.

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a javascript file in minified version. I have lost its original source code. How can i recover my source code from my minified version? 
The variable names are appearing as _1, _2 etc. Is there a way through which i can change the variable names to something meaningful.

Comment: Should've used version control. You can try http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: You can unminify, but you will have to fix the variable names yourself with search/replace.  The original names are not present in the minified file.

Comment: Minification is a lossy process. You will have to rename the variables yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Minification must have just minified the script, but if the variable names have been changed that means you used some kind of an uglifier. There are several online tools available like http://jsbeautifier.org/ that'd help you unminify the code, but uglification can probably not be undone, so you've to rename all your variables manually.

Protip: Use a version control system like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) to keep your revisions/history and also take backups so that you don't loose your source code in future.

I understand strange issues occur, but hope you resolve them. Good Luck!